# How to get limited size scrolledwindow in a wx subwindow?

Tags: wxpython

I want to create a dialog that within it, contains a scrolled window. The scrolled window is not the only thing in the dialog. It's to hold a, possibly long, list of radio buttons.

My application doesn't use the phoenix variant.

How do I set the size of my scrolled window and get scrollbars? The documentation indicates that a call to SetScrollBars is no longer recommended

Here's is my code:

```
import wx

myapp = wx.App( redirect=False )
frame = wx.Frame(None)
main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
frame.SetSizer(main_sizer)

txt = wx.StaticText(frame, -1, "test string" )
main_sizer.Add(txt)

scrollWin = wx.ScrolledWindow(frame, -1)
scrollSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
scrollWin.SetSizer(scrollSizer)

maxx = 0
maxy = 0
for i in range( 50 ) :
    txtStr = " Text %02d " % (i+1)
    stTxt = wx.StaticText( scrollWin, -1, txtStr )
    scrollSizer.Add(stTxt)
    maxx = max(maxx, stTxt.GetSize().x)
    maxy = max(maxy, stTxt.GetSize().y)

scrollWin.SetMaxSize((maxx, maxy*3))


main_sizer.Add(scrollWin, proportion=0)

txt = wx.StaticText(frame, -1, "test string" )
main_sizer.Add(txt)

frame.Fit()
frame.Show()

myapp.MainLoop()
```

Comment: You're on the right track using sizers: When you make your layout inside the scrolled window with sizers, you don't need the call to SetScrollBars. Take a look at the FitInside method; I think this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

Two key things were missing from my original code

1. You have to set the scroll rate
2. You have to add the scrolledWindow to the sizer with the wx.EXPAND flag.

Things that didn't need to be done, or perhaps made it worse

1. EnableScrolling is not needed
2. Fit made it worse. The overall size was way smaller; minimum size. With the above two required code, it still worked but too small to be usable. You'd have to manually resize the window to actually read the contents
3. It doesn't matter if I set sizer early or late (perhaps a runtime difference?)
4. It doesn't matter if I set scroll rate early or late. (using the system font size was a nice trick I found in one of the links. See code.)

SetScrollRate and wx.EXPAND. That's the main thing.

Here is my working code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import wx

myapp = wx.App()


frame = wx.Frame(None)
frame_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
frame.SetSizer(frame_sizer)

txt = wx.StaticText(frame, -1, "test string" )
frame_sizer.Add(txt)

scrollWin = wx.ScrolledWindow(frame, -1)
scrollSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
scrollWin.SetSizer(scrollSizer)
fontsz = wx.SystemSettings.GetFont(wx.SYS_SYSTEM_FONT).GetPixelSize()
scrollWin.SetScrollRate(fontsz.x, fontsz.y)
# doesn't seem to be required
# scrollWin.EnableScrolling(False,True)

for i in range( 20 ) :
    txtStr = " Text %02d " % (i+1)
    stTxt = wx.StaticText( scrollWin, -1, txtStr )
    scrollSizer.Add(stTxt, proportion=0)



# discovered EXPAND in the third example of this page:
# https://wiki.wxpython.org/ScrolledWindows
# documented here:
# https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/sizers_overview.html
frame_sizer.Add(scrollWin, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)

txt = wx.StaticText(frame, -1, "test string" )
frame_sizer.Add(txt)




frame.Show()

myapp.MainLoop()
```